# javascript object hash vs lodash foreach in lodash remove

Tags: javascript, object, hash, foreach, lodash

I'm trying to delete some data from a complex object.

The format of the original data is as follows.

```
let originData = 
[
    {
       name : exampleDepth1,
       depth1Data : 
       [
            {
                 name : exampleDepth2,
                 depth2Data : 
                 [
                     {
                         code: 1234///will be delete from that data
                     },
                     ...
                 ]
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ....
]

let willbeDeletecode = [ 3, 100, 1234, 1000];
```

The name of the array to be deleted is the `code` value in the `depth2Data` array of `originData`, The name of the array to delete is `willbeDeletecode`.

I'm sorry if you were uncomfortable.

I'm trying to erase it in two ways.

```
let deleteBook = {}
_.forEach(willbeDeletecode, (deleteCode) => {
  deleteBook[`${deleteCode}`] = deleteCode;
})

_.remove(originData, (depth1) => {
  _.remove(depth1.depth1Data, (depth2) => {
    /*
    // delete with object hash
    _.remove(depth2.depth2Data, (eachDepth2Data) => {
      return deleteBook[eachDepth2Data.code] === undefined
    })
    */

    /*
    // delete with forEach
    let ret = false;
     _.remove(depth2.depth2Data, (eachDepth2Data) => {
       _.forEach(willbeDeletecode, (deleteCode) => {
         if(deleteCode === eachDepth2Data.code){
             ret = true;
             return false;
            }
        })
        return ret
    })
    */
    return depth2.depth2Data.length === 0;
  })
  return depth1.depth1Data.length === 0;
})
```

I have two separate ways of annotating each one.

The first is to create an object(`deleteBook`) and insert the data of `willbeDeletecode` and use it in remove of lodash.

The second method is entirely a comparison of all through the `forEach` function.

The above method was repeated 1000 times to benchmark. As a result, the first method is 100 ~ 200ms and the second method is 500 ~ 700ms.

Of course, the `willbeDeletecode` is around 10 or so, but I thought Object hash was faster. But the result was the opposite.

If there are more variables in `willbeDeletecode`, will there be another conclusion? I want know why this results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object hash is to be preferred. You could also use an ES6 `Set` for such purpose.

Such a hash solution should be faster.

One reason that you did not see this in your case, is that the first variant of your code removes the *opposite* of what it should. The `_remove` callback should return a truthy value when the corresponding item should be removed, yet your code returns `true` when the value is *not* in the codes that should be deleted. You should use a `!==` comparison:

```
_.remove(depth2.depth2Data, (eachDepth2Data) => {
    return deleteBook[eachDepth2Data.code] !== undefined
})
```

As you had a `===` there, you probably had a lot more removals going on, giving a longer time of execution.